# requireJS causes flickering

Tags: jquery, requirejs

Using RequireJS is causing JavaScript inserted text to flicker on every request (FOUT).

In main.js:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'libs/jQuery-2-0-3'
  }
});

require(['jquery'],
  function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // this div is inserted shortly after the page is loaded
      $('#formWrapper').prepend('<div>testing</div>')
    });
  });
```

And the HTML in the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var require = {
      baseUrl: "/script/",
      deps : ['main']
  };
</script>

<script src="/script/require.js"></script>
```

When I do the same without RequireJS I get no flickering at all:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/libs/jQuery-2-0-3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#formWrapper').prepend('<div>testing</div>')
    });
</script>
```

It is most noticeable in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: requirejs has very little to do with this, it just makes it slightly more obvious since the scripts are loaded a little bit later. Simply put, you're prepending the text so late in the page load cycle that the browser has already rendered before the append happens. It will be less noticeable on fast computers than it will on slow computers. **There are two ways to fix it**: Execute your code earlier, or hide all of the content under a loading bar until the dom has been initialized by your script.

Comment: The cause is due to the fact that with requirejs, you're waiting until the dom is ready to even load jquery, while without it you're loading jquery immediately.

Comment: The flickering also happens when i put the requirejs script at the end of the body tag and excludes the document ready.

Comment: So my code would actually run faster if I did not use requireJS ?

Comment: No, it would run *sooner*, not faster. require.js is a great library, but it does have it's drawbacks. For this particular problem i instead include jquery without requirejs so that it will be immediately available (since jquery should typically be the largest script include on your page) which avoids this problem. Also note that this *problem* should only be a problem on the first page load, subsequent page loads should load jquery much faster if caching is setup properly.

Comment: Probably also important to keep in mind that while this flashing is very irritating to a developer, most site visitors won't even notice it if it's small. If preventing it hinders or modifies your code too much, it may not be worth fixing it. Look at how this webpage loads, there are several parts that flicker.

Comment: The only way i can avoid this problem right now is by using the optimizer to minify and merging the files into one. That was not my original intention.

Comment: @Kevin B. What do you mean by set up the cache? The problem appears even when the files are cached in the browser

Comment: In your browser it does. How fast is your computer? what browser are you using? how big is the DOM you are working with? how long does it take for the server to return the html and how long does it take the network to send it? there are a lot of factors involved.

Comment: I'm not sure about all the factors. Still I don't think this is a libary that takes 'workload off my shoulders'. Taking care of modules and dependencies is nice but you have to deal with all the workarounds for making the page appear as fast as if you were not using requireJS...

Comment: Exactly. you have to weigh the good against the bad. It's a great library for adding organization without too much work on the developer, and it makes it easier for teams of developers to manage dependencies, however, just like any other library or added resource, it has it's drawbacks.

Comment: When using requireJS you can control which pages gets what modules. Is there any advantage of that once the modules are merged into one file ? Or should I ask this in a different post : )